# BigQuery use conditions to create a table from other tables

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I am facing a serious blockage on a project of mine.
Here is the summary of what i would like to do :

I have a big hourly file (10 Go) with the following extract (no header) :

```
ID_A|segment_1,segment_2
ID_B|segment_2,segment_3,segment_4,segment_5
ID_C|segment_1
ID_D|segment_2,segment_4
```

Every ID (from A to D) can be linked to one or multiple segments (from 1 to 5).

I would like to process this file in order to have the following result (the result file contains a header) :

```
ID|segment_1|segment_2|segment_3|segment_4|segment_5
ID_A|1|1|0|0|0
ID_B|0|1|1|1|1
ID_C|1|0|0|0|0
ID_D|0|1|0|1|0
```

**1** means that the ID is included in the segment, **0** means that it is not.

I can clearly do this task by using a python script with multiple loops and conditions, however, i need a fast script that can do the same work.

I would like to use BigQuery to perform this operation.
Is it possible to do such task in BigQuery ?
How can it be done ?

Thanks to all for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that the file is loaded into a BQ table with an `id` column and a `segments` column (which is a string).  Then I would recommend storing the result values as an *array*, but that is not your question.

You can use the following `select` to create the table:

```
select id,
       countif(segment = 'segment_1') as segment_1,
       countif(segment = 'segment_2') as segment_2,
       countif(segment = 'segment_3') as segment_3,
       countif(segment = 'segment_4') as segment_4,
       countif(segment = 'segment_5') as segment_5
from staging s cross join
     unnest(split(segments, ',')) as segment
group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Hello Gordon, this solution worked until the number of segments became a lot higher (900+ segments instead of 5 in my first example).
I am now facing another issue (huge query that cannot be passed as argument through bq cli.
Is there any workaround that i can use ?

Comment: @MustaphaFekir . . . I think you should ask a new question.

Comment: Will do that asap! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  IF('segment_1' IN UNNEST(list), 1, 0) AS segment_1,
  IF('segment_2' IN UNNEST(list), 1, 0) AS segment_2,
  IF('segment_3' IN UNNEST(list), 1, 0) AS segment_3,
  IF('segment_4' IN UNNEST(list), 1, 0) AS segment_4,
  IF('segment_5' IN UNNEST(list), 1, 0) AS segment_5
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(segments) AS list)])
```

Above assumes you have your data in the table like in below TCE

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'ID_A' id, 'segment_1,segment_2' segments UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID_B', 'segment_2,segment_3,segment_4,segment_5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID_C', 'segment_1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID_D', 'segment_2,segment_4' 
)
```

if to apply above query to such data - result will be

```
Row id      segment_1   segment_2   segment_3   segment_4   segment_5    
1   ID_A    1           1           0           0           0    
2   ID_B    0           1           1           1           1    
3   ID_C    1           0           0           0           0    
4   ID_D    0           1           0           1           0
```

Comment: btw, consider voting up on answer if it was helpful, even if for whatever reason another answer is accepted :o)